# Include separately all reference from separate bib files

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm trying to print the bibliography from different `bib` files in different sections.

I know that that the command `\nocite{*}` allows to print all the references, but in my case I want them to be separated according to the file they stand. I don't know if it's quite clear, here is an ECM where I enter by hand all the references for each section, using `refsection`. The output is what I want, but I would prefer not to enter by hand the `nocite` for every reference (and I'm sure it is possible to do so )

```latex
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio1.bib}
\addbibresource{biblio2.bib}

\begin{document}
\section*{Biblio 1}
\begin{refsection}
    \nocite{refA}
    \nocite{refB}
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\section*{Biblio 2}
\begin{refsection}
    \nocite{refC}
    \nocite{refD}
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

with the `bib` files :

```latex
% biblio1.bib
@misc{refA,
    author = {Alfred},
    title = {Amazing book},
    year = {2000},
}

@misc{refB,
    author = {Bruce},
    title = {Best book},
    year = {2021},
}
```

```latex
% biblio2.bib
@misc{refC,
    author = {Craig},
    title = {Catastrophic book},
    year = {2000},
}

@misc{refD,
    author = {Denis},
    title = {Disastrous book},
    year = {2000},
}
```

Here is the output :

[image: output]

Comment: If you can use `biblatex`, it has a `bibbycategory`  function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed restrict the bibresource of a refsection by using the `label` argument of `\addbibresource` and then indicating the label when starting the `refsection`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource[label=biblio1]{biblio1.bib}
\addbibresource[label=biblio2]{biblio2.bib}

\begin{document}
\section*{Biblio 1}
\begin{refsection}[biblio1]
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\section*{Biblio 2}
\begin{refsection}[biblio2]
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]